# Convert a postgres row into golang struct with array field

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlx

I am having postgres db table as

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
name varchar(50),
types varchar(50)[],
role varchar[10]
);
```

and corresponding struct in go:

```
type Foo struct {
Name string `db:"name"`
Types []string `db:"types"`
Role string `db:"role"`
}
```

I want to fetch db rows into my struct. Right now I am able to do this by using:

```
var foo Foo
query := `SELECT name, types, roles FROM foo LIMIT 1`
err = dbConn.QueryRow(query).Scan(&foo.Name,  pq.Array(&foo.Types), &foo.Role)
```

But I want to achieve the same using direct mapping. Something like:

```
var foo []Foo
query := `SELECT name, types, roles FROM foo`
dbWrapper.err = dbConn.Select(&foo, query)
```

Above snippet gives me error because of `Types` being pq array. Is it possible to directly map pq array as a part of struct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44385791/10138004, I am able to solve this pq driver for sqlx (https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq) itself by replacing `[]string` with `pq.StringArray`.

So, updated struct looks like:

```
type Foo struct {
Name string `db:"name"`
Types pq.StringArray `db:"types"` //this is what changed.
Role string `db:"role"`
}
```

and direct mapping is working like a charm now

```
var foo []Foo
query := `SELECT name, types, roles FROM foo`
dbWrapper.err = dbConn.Select(&foo, query)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pg-go` lib for that. Please look at [pg.Model()](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-pg/pg#Model). It's possible to pass an entire struct to it.